# GTK# - PropertyNotifyEvent doesn't seem to work

Tags: events, mono, event-handling, xamarin-studio, gtk#

I try to make my app to react on property change of a widget, but the signal PropertyNotifyEvent is never invoke.
For test purpose i make a very simple application containing a label and a button. Pressing the button change text property of label but the PropertyNotifyEvent isn't responding.

```
using System;
using Gtk;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build();
    label1.AddEvents((int)(Gdk.EventMask.PropertyChangeMask));
}

protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
{
    Application.Quit();
    a.RetVal = true;
}

protected void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "new text";
}

protected void OnLabel1PropertyNotifyEvent(object o, PropertyNotifyEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("label property change");
}
}
```

I have no idea what I do wrong, do I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
label1.AddNotification("label", (o, args) => {Console.WriteLine("label property change");});
```